# Checking if pictures exist on separate domain

Tags: php, mysql, image, cross-domain

So I'm working on a website where the images for a directory are listed on a separate domain than the database/website that has the directory. The way it has been set up, is the families last name plus the spouses first initials make up the image name, so that...

```
John and Kathy Doe
```

would correspond to the image:

```
doe-jk.jpg
```

What I want to do, is in the logic that displays each listing from the database, it checks to see if this image exists on the other domain, something like this:

```
$picture_name = "http://totally-different-domain.com/".$file_name;
    if ( isset( $picture_name ) )
    {
       echo $picture_name;
    }
    else
    {
       echo 'empty.jpg';
    }
```

**Does anybody know how I can do this when the files exist on separate domains?**

EDIT: What I mean by separate domains, is that the script exists at http://domain1.com/directory.php, and the image that is included in directory.php is at http://totally-different-domain.com/doe-jk.jpg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check if a file exists on another domain by using the get_headers function and checking if you get a 404. Ex.

```
$url = 'http://totally-different-domain.com/doe-jk.jpg'
$response = get_headers($url, 1);
$file_exists = (strpos($response[0], "404") === false);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with directories: the response is 404 even though the directory exists.

Answer (score 2):

[`is_readable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) checks both for existence and readability.

```
$picture_name = "http://totally-different-domain.com/".$file_name;
if (!is_readable($picture_name)) {
    $picture_name = 'empty.jpg';
}
echo $picture_name;
```

Comment: Note that as per [is-readable#61293](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php#61293), `is-readable` may return true even for HTTP errors (e.g. 500, 403 etc). I haven't checked this but you may need to use @jhchen's solution with a status code whitelist (2**, 301 etc) instead of a blacklist (404).